# XAML Code Behind file and MVC

Tags: wpf, silverlight, model-view-controller, xaml

Does the code behind file have the same purpose as a Control class of MVC or the Boundary-Control-Entity Pattern?

I did some small projects with Silverlight and WPF, and most of the time I pretty much put the logic in the code behind file. Though with references to other classes. Not everything in the code behind.

What was/is the initial purpose of the code behind file and how do most of you use it?

Thanks,

Grant

Answer (score 0):

The preferred design pattern for developing Silverlight applications is MVVM, in which the View Model is closer to taking over the role of a controller in MVC.  When using the MVVM pattern, I'd only use the code behind of controls to implement UI-only (view-only) logic that has little to do with the data, such as performing animations and other special effects.

Comment: Interessting. I've never heard of MVVM. Going to do some reading on that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Originally, the code-behind file, in conjunction with data converters in WPF, served the same purpose as the code-behind in VB6, C#, VB.NET, what have you. It is primarily a place to put code that responds to UI events. However, in the case of WPF and Silverlight, coding in the code-behind file is potentially very messy and can easily lead to maintenance problems later on, if there is anything more than the simplest program to be implemented.

"Model-View-ViewModel" (MVVM) was conceived, I think, late in the development of WPF; Silverlight was conceived later than MVVM. Near as I can tell. Not every consultant I've heard talking about WPF or Silverlight is convinced that MVVM is "the preferred" design pattern, but it is a solid abstraction model.

WPF isn't as well tooled as WinForms, even today. This is part of what makes it potentially very messy with the potential maintenance problems. MVVM, as a design pattern, makes up for a lot of the drawbacks stemming from the immaturity of XAML and WPF/Silverlight as a user interface model, while bringing forward most of the tremendous advantages offered by XAML and WPF.

Summaries of MVVM are available [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel), [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johngossman/archive/2005/10/08/478683.aspx8/478683.aspx), and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx). Josh Smith is a leading authority on the pattern, he sells a book called "[Advanced MVVM](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/advanced-mvvm/)" which I'm told is useful; I was able to implement some complex implementations without it, though.

Comment: Thank you for the brief explanation. 

What other design patterns are commonly used for WPF/Silverlight development?

Comment: MVVM gets so much more noise with respect to WPF/Silverlight than any other pattern that it can be very hard to tell. MVC and MVP patterns will also work. Sad to say, though, it's really up to you to choose a design pattern, or not, depending on your need.  Personally, I've used Model-View-Controller with a degree of success, where the View classes had enough knowledge of the Controller to set a property, which breaks a couple of MVVM rules, but my application was relatively simple. I've avoided EF patterns because I've been told that any use of EF before EF 4 was too full of caveats.